# Adjust coordinates of clicking while expanding page

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm making a canvas game here:
http://www.codecademy.com/IStoleThePies/codebits/UJFpg4/edit

It acts as a point-and-click game, where clicking on the door would open it. I do this by setting coordinates in which I can click, and get a response:

```
function on_canvas_click(ev) {
    var x = ev.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = ev.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (x >= 205 && y >= 360 && x <= 295 && y <= 500 && hasItem == false && doorOpen == false) {
        alert("The door is locked, but a key might open it");
    }
```

However, I also tried to make the entire canvas increase in size depending on the size of the monitor. I did not want the entire canvas length and width to increase, but rather make the entire game bigger, so I did the following:

CSS:

```
#myCanvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    canvas.addEventListener('click', on_canvas_click, false);
    canvas.width  = window.innerWidth-430;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight-200;
```

I hoped that this would increase the size of the game while also keeping it somewhat proportional to what it would normally look like. However, this interfered with the coordinates of the click-range for the door. Now, I can't click on the door and have it respond. I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: See if this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522895/javascript-track-mouse-position-within-video/29527843#29527843